# Stone-Weierstrass like theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

> Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(x) = f(-x),$ for all $x \in [-1,1].$ Show that for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is a polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coefficients such that for every $x \in [-1,1],$ $$\left \lvert f(x) - p(x^2) \right \rvert \lt \varepsilon.$$

How do I prove this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual challenge I'm facing is to make all the coefficients of $p$ rational. May be by denseness of rationals we can do that. But I failed to find any rigorous proof of it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first prove the following.

1. Suppose $p$ is a polynomial on $[-1, 1]$ and let $\varepsilon>0.$ There exists a polynomial $q$ With rational coefficients such that $\|p-q\|<\varepsilon.$

Proof. To see this let $\deg(p)=n$ and let $p(z)=a_nz^n+\ldots+a_0.$ Choose rationals $b_i$ such that $|a_i-b_i|<\varepsilon/(n+1).$ Now observe that for any $x\in [-1, 1]$ we have $|p(X)-q(x)|<\varepsilon.$

Now, the second thing that need to proved is that an even function $f$ Can be approximated by an even polynomial in $x^2.$ I believe (because of your comment) that you have no difficulty in showing this.

I hope you can now see how your claim follows.

Comment: Now for any $x \in [0,1]$ define a new function $g$ defined by $g(x) = f(\sqrt x).$ Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,1].$ Take any sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x) \}_{n \geq 1}$ converging uniformly to $g$ on $[-1,1].$ Fix $\varepsilon \gt 0$ arbitrarily. Then $\exists$ a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ and for all $y \in [0,1]$ $$|g(y) - p_n(y)| \lt \varepsilon\ \  \text {i.e.}\ \ |f(\sqrt y) - p_n(y)| \lt \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Putting $x = \sqrt y$ we have for all $n \geq N$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$ we have $$|f(x) - p_n(x^2)| \lt \varepsilon.$$ Since $f$ is symmetric about origin and $(-x)^2 = x^2,$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ so if we replace $x$ by $-x$ by similar argument it follows that for all $n \geq N$ and for all $x \in [-1,0]$ we have $$|f(x) - p_n (x^2)| \lt \varepsilon.$$ Fixing $n = N$ we find a polynomial $p_N(x)$ such that for all $x \in [-1,1]$ we have $$|f(x) - p_N (x^2)| \lt \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Is my argument fine for the second part?

Comment: In the first comment I'm actually taking a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x) \}_{n \geq 1}$ converging uniformly to $g$ on $[0,1];$ not on $[-1,1].$ This is possible by Stone-Weierstrass theorem since $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1].$ All the other steps are ok. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! You are right!

Comment: @Anacardium Just a minor point: In your first comment you should have $p_n$ converging to $g$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$ (not on $[-1, 1]$).

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying. Are you from India?

Comment: See my last comment @WhoKnowsWho. I have already mentioned that.

Comment: Ahh! I missed your last comment! Your proof is perfect! (P.S.: Yes, I am from India.)

Comment: Where are you from? I am from Kolkata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112918/discussion-between-anacardium-and-whoknowswho).